# GUI shapes border checking (FLOWCHART CONNECTOR)

Tags: user-interface, shapes, flowchart, connector

So I'm working on a Flowchart (OOP) Program, and I have to implement a code for Connector, which has the condition that it must be between 2 other shapes.

So the question here is how to check if the user click is within a "shape" area ?

Like I can "GetMouseClick" as a function, but I need to check if this point lies in a shape from the shapes drawn.

NOTE : Each shape has a class !

Answer (score 0):

For each class (shape) define a getBounds(...) method that will return the rectangle (or a polygon) and when you click you can iterate over all shapes and see within what bounds the click was.

Another idea is to add mouse listener for each shape and rely on event handler to tell you what shape was clicked.

Comment: I thought of this idea, Thanks for giving me this advice.

But I faced another problem, that within my IF condition, I had to create an array of pointers to these statement as to store the shapes drawn inside it, and check with a for loop inside the IF statement with the boundaries, it gave me an error for the word "for" saying Expected an Expression !

Comment: Without a code example is hard to further help (beside concept)